# Is it possible to delete keyTyped and keyReleased methods in Java?

Tags: java

I have added a new keyListener to my JFrame. IntelliJ Idea generated the methods keyTyped, keyPressed and keyReleased for me. I only need the keyPressed method so i would like to delete the others. If i do this, i get the Error: 
`java: "classname" is not abstract and does not override abstract method keyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent) in java.awt.event.KeyListener`

```
@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    //do something
}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
}
```

Comment: No, you cannot skip these methods since they are defined in the [`KeyListener` interface](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/event/KeyListener.html). You can, however, leave them empty. I would recommend reading a tutorial on interfaces, e.g. [this one by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/createinterface.html).

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyAdapter.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot, no. `KeyListener` is an interface, and when implementing a concrete class that `implements` an interface, it is required to implement all methods.

You can, however, use `java.awt.event.KeyAdapter` instead of `KeyListener`. As this is an `abstract class`, you'll need to `extends KeyAdapter` instead of `implements KeyListener`.

This has empty methods defined for all `KeyListener` methods, so you only need to write methods for the events you wish to handle.

Answer (score 0):

Use KeyAdapter instead of KeyLestener, and override the method you need.

```
KeyAdapter keyAdapter = new KeyAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

    }
};
```